# Kotlin : getResources() on a null object reference

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-context

I have create array of color like this in kotlin

```
private var colorArray = arrayOf(
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_yellow),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_green),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_red)
)
```

and when i want to get color from **colorArray** through index

```
var color = colorArray[0]
```

I am getting crash on index 0,

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

I don't know where i am wrong
If i write ***ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_yellow)*** this is fine no crash but through array index it give me error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring this as a field:

```
private var colorArray = arrayOf(
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_yellow),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_green),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_red)
)
```

The issue is that your context (the `this` parameter) is null before your `onCreate()` method is called. And when you declare something as a field, it tries to initialise it immediately, before any method calls. (So before the `onCreate` is called)

What you can do is initialise this field with a `lazy` call.
This means that it is actually only initialised when it is first used. So if you're calling the index AFTER your `onCreate`, the context won't be null and it should work fine.

Change it to:

```
private var colorArray by lazy { arrayOf(
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_yellow),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_green),
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.text_red)
) }
```

Comment: How is it possible, that `this` is null?

Comment: Because the array is created when the class instance is created. This happens before the onCreate call (the point at which 'this' becomes not null).

Comment: Because the Android framework initialises the `Context` in the `onCreate` of an Activity. `this` here is referring to the context. It simply hasn't been initialised yet, so it's `null` until the `onCreate` is called

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` as `Context` globally which is not initialized yet .
This is why you are getting this error cause `Context` is null.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()

The Right way to do this access the context inside `onCreate()`. You can try something like below:-

```
class Dx :AppCompatActivity(){
private lateinit var colorArray:Array<Int>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dx)
    colorArray = arrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    )
    val btn=findViewById<Button>(R.id.b1)
    btn.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[0])
}
}
```